# How to show a custom notification when receive FCM from background in Flutter App?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, custom-notification

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkY2w.png)Im doing a chat & voip app using Flutter.
I'm facing a problem when trying to implement custom notification when user has an incoming call.

When the app is in foreground, the custom notification'll show well.
Problem is: when app terminated or in background, the custom notification won't show.

I've tried some ways else:

- Listen to FCM in native code (MyFirebaseMessagingService, in onMessageReceived I call showNotification() but it won't show, too
- Follow these steps in this Medium article: https://medium0.com/@info_67212/firebase-push-notification-with-action-button-in-flutter-a841da348097. It doesnt work, too

Pls help me. Thank you very much

In main.dart

```
 Future<void> _connectToAndroid() async {
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('connect');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("EXCEPTION $e");
    }
  }

  void firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) iOS_Permission();
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      tokenFirebase = token;
      print('token $token');
    });

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on 1111msg  $message');
        _connectToAndroid();
        _showNotification(jsonDecode(message['data']['ntf_data'])['title'], jsonDecode(message['data']['ntf_data'])['message'], jsonDecode(message['data']['ntf_data'])['conversationId']);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on resume $message');
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on launch $message');
      },
    );
  }
```

and in MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "connect"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            Log.e("MainActivity", "CHANNEL")
                result.success(null)
                showNotification()
        }
    }

    private fun showNotification() {
        val customView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.custom_notification)
        //       val notificationIntent = Intent(this, CustomDialog::class.java)
//        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
//        val hungupPendingIntent = PendingIn4tent.getBroadcast(this, 0, hungupIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
//        val answerPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, answerIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val channel = NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID", "name", importance).apply {
                description = "descriptionText"
            }
            // Register the channel with the system
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

            val newMessageNotification = Notification.Builder(context, "CHANNEL_ID")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                    .setContentText("IncomingCall")
                    .setTicker("Call_STATUS")
                    .setTimeoutAfter(5000)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                    .setCustomContentView(customView)
                    .build()
            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)) {
                // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
                notify(11111111, newMessageNotification)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Log

```
2021-01-08 15:24:10.141 32759-3385/com.meeyland.meeyteam W/FirebaseMessaging: Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.
2021-01-08 15:24:10.213 32759-2410/com.meeyland.meeyteam V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2021-01-08 15:24:10.239 32759-2410/com.meeyland.meeyteam D/FA: Connected to remote service
2021-01-08 15:24:10.241 32759-2410/com.meeyland.meeyteam V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
2021-01-08 15:24:15.312 32759-2410/com.meeyland.meeyteam V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2021-01-08 15:24:15.319 32759-2410/com.meeyland.meeyteam W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lu@7ace62f
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1751)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1777)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:741)
        at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516083@20.45.16 (120408-0):1)
        at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516083@20.45.16 (120408-0):2)
        at lv.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516083@20.45.16 (120408-0):9)
        at lf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516083@20.45.16 (120408-0):3)
        at ef.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516083@20.45.16 (120408-0):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at iy.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516083@20.45.16 (120408-0):5)
```

Comment: Did you make any progress on getting this to work with a custom FirebaseMessagingService?

Comment: oh yes, i did..